# Open pop-up windows info, after client logout

Tags: magento, popup, frontend, logout

I'm trying to do something that should be quite easy, but after a while I realize that can be tricky in Magento.
So, my goal is pop-up (or pop-down) an windows that display information for the client that just logout. In my logout Success it just redirect to main page after 5 seconds.

The correct place to do it in the code/file I suppose that will be here (logout.phtml):

```
    <div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->__('You are now logged out') ?></h1>
</div>
<p><?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->__('You have logged out and will be redirected to our homepage in 5 seconds.') ?></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    setTimeout(function(){ location.href = '<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>'},5000);
//]]>
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do what you are trying to do by editing that template.  Does your JS code not end up being output?  If not, make sure you are editing the right logout.phtml, depending on how your themes are setup there could be several.  There's a developer setting to show the full path to blocks when viewing a page, that can be very helpful in making sure you are editing the correct template.

Also, I'm not sure if your JS code is just a test to see if it's being output, but it doesn't look like it would popup a window even if it were correctly output.  The code looks like it would just redirect the user back to the main page of your site.

If you're looking for the JS code to create a popunder window, then something basic like this should work:

```
window.open('http://yoursite.com/popunder.html','Pop Under Window','').blur();
window.focus();
```

You can set the window attributes as you see fit by using the 3rd parameter of the open function.